# Python while loop basics, check order of the list

Tags: python, loops

I want to check if element in list is smaller than the next one and break function in a moment when it is not. I have written this code and I am not sure what is wrong because output is [1] when it should be [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. It is probably small error, but I have none to ask..

```
def check_order(a):
  i = 0
  while i < (len(a)-1):
    b = []
    if a[i] < a[(i + 1)]:
        b.insert(i, a[i])
        i = i + 1
        return b
    else:
        break

    
a = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 10]

print(check_order(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues, you are redefining b on every loop, and also returning early inside the if statement

```
def check_order(a):
    i = 0
    b = []
    while i < (len(a) - 1):
        if a[i] < a[(i + 1)]:
            b.insert(i, a[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            break
    return b
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and good explanation:)))

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand what will happen `return` statement is called.

when you call the return statement the flow will return to the function calling the place

[image]

So during the first loop it self when it comes 8th line control will come back to 11th line . So output is only [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x03G2.png)

so you can change something like below

```
def check_order(a):
    i = 0
    b = []
    while i < (len(a) - 1):
        if a[i] < a[(i + 1)]:
            b.insert(i, a[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            break
    return b

a = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 10]

print(check_order(a))
```

Here we have return at end of while loop , So the control from return will come to function call at end of while loop